# imagemagick maxing out at 950px

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick

I'm using code ignitor to do some image resizing which uses imagemagick. it works like magick  :P

the only issue is when i upload the image I want it to resize to 1280px, but it seems to be maxing out at 950px. It looks like that is the max width. i was thinking maby you may be able  to remove update the php.ini file to 1280px.

does any one know how to update this? Or if there some way around it?

Comment: Can you post the config you've passed to the upload library?

Comment: How do you know it's maxing out at 950px? Is it not outputting the image larger than that or is the script choking if you set a dimension larger than it? If it's choking, then there may be a problem with the script itself causing a memory limit or dimension limit to occur, usually caused by an arithmetic operation being done wrong. Please post your code so we can see.